# persist object in postgresql database with anorm in a play framework 2

Tags: postgresql, scala, playframework-2.2, anorm

I'm trying to persist objects to a postgresql Db inside my play2 webapp using anorm library.
The Create statement of the table "Address" is this one:

```
create table address (
    addressId               bigserial not null,
    addressName             varchar(255) not null,
    street                  varchar(255) not null,
    number                  varchar(15) not null,
    ZIP                     varchar(15) not null,
    region                  varchar(63) not null,
    country                 varchar(63) not null,
    constraint pk_address primary key (addressId)
);
```

And my Scala/Anorm code looks like this:

```
private def create(address: Address, recursive : Boolean): Long = {
    DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
        SQL( """
             insert into {table_name} (addressName, street, number, ZIP, region, country)
             values ({name},{street},{number},{ZIP},{region},{country})
            """).on(
            "table_name" -> TABLE_NAME,
            "name" -> address.name,
            "street" -> address.street,
            "number" -> address.number,
            "ZIP" -> address.ZIP,
            "region" -> address.region,
            "country"-> address.country
        ).executeInsert[Option[Long]]().get
    }
}
```

Obviously TABLE_NAME is a val that contains the string "Address"

The problem is that when i try to execute it with a proper Address instance like:

```
Address("Antonio","vacchi","12","48012","RA","Italia")
```

I get this exception:

```
[PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "$1" Posizione: 13]
```

'Posizione' is the italian word for Position (dunno why i get the error in italian o:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the interpolation with the `{table_name}` syntax will result in the SQL containing a positioned parameter. This is something that is not supported when it comes to CREATE statements. So in this case you have to write out `Address` and not pass it in the `on` parameters.

Comment: You saved my day/night ;) 
Don't know why I wasn't thinking at it like a pretty wrapper of prepared Statements ;) Thank you!